# Making JSON page which renders on document ready indexable

Tags: javascript, googlebot

I have a page which is pretty much 99% on document ready generated by various JS files.

It then gets and renders tons of JSON (I use tempo JS for rendering).

It all happens on document ready. So normal human browser will see nice HTML page - I wonder what can I do to make my pages content indexable by google?

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild the foundation of your site using [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Well in general I follow  Progressive enhancement loading more and more JSON in some order=) Only thing is - I start with nearly blank page in HTML content terms=)

Comment: Btw - say I can generate all I create dinamically as plain old HTML on server side - how then to tall crollers that 4-10 difrent html pure data pages that I provide to them shall all be indexed as one page for user with difrent url?

Comment: You have links to them. And possibly make use of the History API.